# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) with Faraday post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, faraday

I'm trying to send http post request from my application using [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) gem, but I keep receiving this error `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)` in that line `response = connection.post '/submissions' do |request|`

and here is my code

```
def post_submission
  connection = Faraday.new(url: URL, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
  response = connection.post '/submissions' do |request|
    request.params = { base64_encoded: false, wait: true }
    request.body = JSON.generate(
      source_code: @params[:source_code],
      stdin: @params[:input],
      expected_output: @problem.output,
      anguage_id: @programming_languge.judge_code
    )
  end
end
```

No matter what updates I do to the code, I keep receiving the same error, even when I don't add any arguments! I tried every way in the documentation to create the connection and the request but all give me the same error, anyone could help, please?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: Screen from the error
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `Faraday.new`'s has keywords arguments?

Comment: @GilgHim Yes, it's here in [Faraday usage] (https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/) `conn = Faraday.new(url: 'http://httpbingo.org', params: {param: '1'}, headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})`

Comment: did you try to `post('/submissions')` instead of the current code ?

Comment: Don't you get a line number with the error message?

Comment: @GilgHim Yes I tried it and it gives the same error

Comment: @user1934428 it is this line `response = connection.post '/submissions' do |request|`

Comment: Can't be. In this line, you invoke `post` with a single argument, but Ruby complains that you pass 2 arguments.

Comment: @user1934428 I updated the question and added screenshot from the error

Comment: Do you get better information when clicking on "full trace"? The bottom-most trace entry should list the name of the offending method.

Comment: @user1934428 it gives me all the positions where I use this `post_submission` method

Comment: Just to make sure that your line numbers are not off-by-one somehow, I would put some debug statement just after setting `connection`; just to ensure that execution really gets so far.

Comment: Can you please share the faraday version and ruby version for this project

Comment: @Ankit I'm using `ruby 2.7.5` and for Faraday I'm just using `gem 'faraday'` and `gem 'faraday-net_http'`